# MySQL Server Error 1064 on custom stored procedure?

Tags: mysql

**This is in MySQL Server.
PROBLEM:**  Using the My Guitar Shop database you installed in Module 1, develop the following queries. Write a script that creates and calls a stored procedure named insert_category. First, code a statement that creates a procedure that adds a new row to the Categories table. To do that, this procedure should have one parameter for the category name. Code at least two CALL statements that test this procedure. (Note that this table doesn’t allow duplicate category names.) Execute the query and take a screenshot of the query and the results.

**I currently have this as my code:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_category;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_category
(
var_category_id INT,
var_category_name varchar(50)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE sql_error TINYINT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
SET sql_error = TRUE;
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE categories
SET
category_id = var_category_id
WHERE
category_name = var_category_name;
IF sql_error = FALSE THEN
COMMIT;
ELSE
ROLLBACK;
END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
-- Test fail:
call insert_category (3,'Basses');
-- Test pass:
call insert_category (4,'Piano');
```

I am getting this error though. "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5." Line 5 is var_category_id INT,
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I ran your code on my development server without a problem. Voting to close as 'not reproducible'.

Comment: Me too - however your logic is flawed as an update that does not find a row to update will not trigger an error , you need to test for existence before update and code accordingly.

Comment: BTW the question says 'creates a procedure that adds a new row to the Categories table' This would be an INSERT rather than an UPDATE.

Comment: If you are - as you specifically state - using MySQL, then don't tag other database engines.